# If/else statement inside the same div tag (formatting)

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to get the formatting of php and html in the same document right. I can't seem to get the conversion right. 
....

This is the original HTML:

```
<div class="content-holder clearfix">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="title-header" class="span12">
            <div class="page-header">
          <?php get_template_part("static/static-title"); ?>
            </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                <?php if ($masonrycategory=='false') { ?>
                    <div class="span8 <?php if (of_get_option('blog_sidebar_pos')==''){echo 'right';}else{echo of_get_option('blog_sidebar_pos'); } ?>" id="content">
                        <?php get_template_part("loop/loop-blog-main"); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span4 sidebar" id="sidebar">
                        <?php dynamic_sidebar("hs_main_sidebar"); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php }else{ ?>
                    <div class="span12 id="content">
                        <?php get_template_part("loop/loop-blog-masonry"); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I need to convert it to PHP.
...

```
    } else {

echo "<div class='content-holder clearfix'>";
    echo "<div class='container'>";
        echo "<div class='row'>";
            echo "<div class='span12'>";
                echo "<div class='row'>";
                    echo "<div id='title-header' class='span12'>";
            echo "<div class='page-header'>";
           get_template_part("static/static-title"); 
            echo "</div>"; 
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<div class='row'>"
                if ($masonrycategory=='false') { 
                    echo "<div class='span8' . 'if (of_get_option('blog_sidebar_pos')==''){echo 'right';}else{echo of_get_option('blog_sidebar_pos'); } ?>" id="content">
                        <?php get_template_part("loop/loop-blog-main"); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span4 sidebar" id="sidebar">
                        <?php dynamic_sidebar("hs_main_sidebar"); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php }else{ ?>
                    <div class="span12 id="content">
                        <?php get_template_part("loop/loop-blog-masonry"); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
} ?>
```

Comment: You don't need to "convert" anything to PHP. Your original document is perfectly valid PHP.

Comment: just save the HTML file as a PHP file.

Comment: You might find a decent IDE helpful in highlighting syntax errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax error:

```
echo "<div class='span8' . 'if (of_get_option('blog_sidebar_pos')==''){echo 'right';}else{echo of_get_option('blog_sidebar_pos'); } ?>" id="content">
```

Until you are more confident, you might find it easier to be more vebose in your style of coding:

```
echo '<div class="span8';
if (of_get_option('blog_sidebar_pos') == '') {
    echo ' right';
} else {
    echo of_get_option('blog_sidebar_pos');
}
echo '" id="content">';
```

Comment: That seems to work in some way, however, the HTML output for "right" is still not correct: <div class="span8" right id="content"> but the "right" should be inside the class...

Comment: Ah ok - I have edited my answer above to add "right" to the class attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can use the if else shorthand like this:

```
div class="span8 <?php $v= (of_get_option('blog_sidebar_pos')=='')? 'right':of_get_option('blog_sidebar_pos') ;echo $v;?>" id="content">
```

Considering of_get_option fn does't have any error.

Comment: Even shorter: you don't have to define the `$v` variable. Just `echo ( some case is true ) ? 'true case' : 'false case';`.